# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll - InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have Office 365 installed on my machine. Particularly MS Word version is 2012.

I have created C# project (VS 2019) and referenced microsoft word 16.0 object. It appeared as C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll.

at that following code

```
Application application = new Application();
var document = application.Documents.Open(args[0])
```

throws

**System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0002096B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155).'
exception.**

I have checked \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\Interface{0002096B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\TypeLib registry entry and it is empty (my machine is 64 bit).

I tried to run my executable on other machines but  got the same error. Please advise.

Comment: Can you not use `var` for `application`?

Comment: No, it didn't help. But

            `Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");`
            `dynamic application = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);`

started to work. Not sure what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `var application = new Application();`.

Comment: I got it. var `application = new Application()`; didn't work

Comment: In what way didn't it work? It should have at least given you a new error.

Comment: no, with var it was giving the same error.